# `sudo` to to connect to wifi with root permissions from C

Tags: c, linux

i would like to know is there any way to connect to wifi AP by using C file? currently i use this code

```
 system("sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid home")
```

but i want the user to type the ssid. is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can prompt the user to input that SSID, then construct the command that will be runned by `system()`:

```
char ssid[100];
char cmd[200];
printf("Which AP you want to connect: ");
scanf(" %100[0-9a-zA-Z_-]", ssid);
snprintf(cmd, 200, "sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid %s", ssid);
system(cmd);
```

Comment: already try and it give me error "error for wireless request "set essid" (8B1A)

Comment: @user2906282 Print that `cmd` before you run it to make sure you are running the correct command.

Comment: IMHO, feeding unvalidated user input to `system` is _always_ bad practice. The code should either properly escape `ssid` or use one of the `exec*` functions instead of `system`.

Comment: @Phillip Yes, you are correct. Feeding user input gathered through `scanf("%s", ...);` to `system()` is too dangerous. Beside escape `ssid`, another option is using `[` of `scanf()` to specify the allowed characters in `ssid`. Answer updated. Thank you for point that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `wpa_supplicant` then you can follow these steps to connect to your wireless network using below settings:

- check the config file location passed to the wpa_supplicant.

  ps -eaf | grep wpa*

You can get the details about the conf file from [here](http://hostap.epitest.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf). Lets say your config file is at location **/usr/etc/wifi.conf**.
Add the network details from your c code by appending the network information based on your network configuration at the end of the file as shown below :

```
network={
ssid="simple"
psk="very secret passphrase"
  }
```

The above syntax may change for different network types. After closing the config file issue the `reconfigure` command & it will connect you to wireless network.

You can also use `wpa_cli` command line tool for the above purpose. For more information on wpa_cli take a look [here](http://rtl8192cu.googlecode.com/hg-history/bdd3a2265bdd6a92f24cef3d52fa594b2844c9c1/document/wpa_cli_with_wpa_supplicant.pdf).